# How can I use htaccess to protect a subdirectory of codeigniter installation?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, basic-authentication, subdirectory

I have codeigniter installed at the root directory, and would like to have a subdirectory called "test" password protected using htaccess.  I keep getting a "404 page not found" no matter what I try.  The directory structure is:

```
/public_html  
    /css  
    /images
    /system (codeigniter directory)
    /test
        .htaccess
.htaccess
.htpasswd
index.php
```

The root .htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Options -Indexes    

# Removes trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]


#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)test(.*)    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

The /test/.htaccess file:

```
AuthUserFile /home/dir/.htpasswd
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthType Basic
<limit GET POST PUT>
  require user adminuser
</limit>
```

I'm not even getting the authentication prompt, just the codeigniter 404 page when I navigate to the url "http://www.mydomain.com/test/".

Please advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I finally solved it (found solution in CodeIgniter forum at http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/56677/P15/):

I had this line to my root htaccess:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(401.shtml)
```

So the final block in my root htaccess ended up looking like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(401.shtml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

So relieved a solution was out there.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|addFoldersHere)
```

Try this in place of your current RewriteCond rule in your main .htaccess. This will allow folders you specify (where it says `addFoldersHere`) to not be ignored. Make sure you don't add a trailing `|` after the list of folder(s).